# save an .owl file where opened from url in protégé

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I downloaded dron ontology using protégé "open from url".In it's .owl file is just a series of urls that protégé using these urls to load them from internet.
I'm saving the project but the only thing that is saving is the original file(the file witch contain urls) and every time I should get all of data from the internet.what should I do to save complete file on my computer disk?

Comment: Save all imported ontologies and adapt the IRIs in the import declarations to the corresponding file paths. Or save all imported axioms into a single ontology file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a copy of the ontology and of each imported ontology to the same folder. Next time you open it in Protege, a catalog.xml file should be created, and Protege will use the local copies.

This should work as long as the ontology IRI for the imported ontologies matches the import IRI in the main ontology - i.e., if the ontology IRI matches the URL for the ontology document. If that's not the case, Protege won't be able to know which ontology is at the remote site without downloading it; in that case you have to follow AKSW's comment and change the import axioms.